# Edit an existing feed URL in Google Reader to new RSS location

Tags: google-reader, feeds

How do you update the feed URL of a subscription through Google Reader?

Subscribed to a blog that used to publish their RSS feed at the following:

```
http://example.com/blog/feed
```

But now it's dead as the new hotness is located at:

```
http://example.com/feed
```

301 redirect on their end wasn't set up correctly to point to the new location and/or it was just dropped like a hot potato and left to 404.

You can rename a blog feed to whatever name you like. Can't seem to find where to update the feed URL if the source has moved locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit a feed location in Google Reader.

You will have to delete the subscription that points to the old URL and then add a new subscription using the new URL.

Comment: That blows chunks having to re-add *and* re-label it

Answer (score 0):

Refer [thread](http://markmail.org/message/zmvvthldbsb6kbcw#query%3aedit%20feed%20url%20in%20google%20reader+page:1+mid%3azmvvthldbsb6kbcw+state%3aresults) which talk about the same.

Delete the old one and add a new subscription it will fetch all feeds and no need to worry about history.